# Save marked book titles in an Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, cookies

So I have a PHP script, connected to a db with a lot of ebooks(title,author etc.)
and I want to add a button, which lets you mark it as "interested" and shows them later on, at a different page.

I don't expect to get any code from you though some hints on where to start would be nice. 
(It's an exercise and I don't know which part of the code you may need)

The books are not supposed to be marked permanent. So I don't want to work with an extra database.
I thought about adding values to an array when clicked on the button(e.g: the title)and storing it afterward in a session or cookie.

For example, when you press the button it adds the title to an array which will be saved in a session or cookie and shown later on at a different page.

I appreciate every help.

Comment: any code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks an "interested" button, you can use AJAX to submit it to a PHP script that'll add the book IDs to an Array stored in a Session. And whenever you want to retrieve the books the user is interested in, you just retrieve the books from the database using the IDs that were stored earlier in the $_SESSION variable.